# SQL count names and OS

Tags: sql, count

I have a table that looks like this:

```
PC-Name     OperatingSystem
-------     ---------------
Dep01-pc1   Win7
Dep01-pc2   WinXP
Dep02-pc1   Win7
Dep02-pc2   Win7
```

And I want to query that will put out result like that:

```
Department    PC-Count  Win7-Count    WinXP-Count
----------    --------  ----------    -----------
Dep01         2         1             1
Dep02         2         2             0
```

Is that even possible to do in a single query?

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT() FROM table WHERE department LIKE '%01'),
    (SELECT COUNT() FROM table WHERE department LIKE '%01' and OS like 'Win7')
```

Thanks!

Comment: select (select count(*) from table where department like '%01'), (select count(*) from table where department like '%01' and OS like 'Win7')

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, but this does the trick:

```
SELECT Department
    ,COUNT(*) AS 'Department Count'
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN OS LIKE 'Win7%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS '7 Count'
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN OS LIKE 'WinXP%'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'XP Count'
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT([PC-Name], CHARINDEX('-', [PC-Name]) - 1) AS 'Department'
        ,SUBSTRING([PC-Name], CHARINDEX('-', [PC-Name], 1) + 1, LEN([PC-Name]) - CHARINDEX('-', [PC-Name], 1)) AS 'Name'
        ,OS
    FROM machines
    ) x
GROUP BY Department
```

[image]